# Bootstrap tooltip wrong position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a simple laravel application where i like to use bootstrap tooltip.

Table:

```
            <table id="tableSequence" class="table" style="font-size: 12px">
                    <tr style="font-weight: 600">
                            <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on left">EZ</td>
                            <td>MZ</td>
                            <td>WZ</td>
                            <td>EP</td>
                            <td>MP</td>
                            <td>WP</td>
                            <td>SZ</td>
                            <td>TZ</td>
                            <td>SP</td>
                            <td>TP</td>
                    </tr>
```

JS

```
    $(function(){

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({

    });

});
```

When i hoover EZ, the tooltip is shown on the left side of the screen:

[image]

Do I have to add additional code to place the tooltip near of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get it working with bootstrap. Therefor I used [Toltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started)
Now it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **data-placement** to other than top. This issue is with your layout. Give link for testing. It could be better to solve.

Comment: I have the same result with data-placement right, left and bottom

Comment: can you please share link for test ?

Comment: I got something. I think is bad but it will work. 
Add css to this class and adjust tooltip as your need.

.ui-tooltip {
    position: relative !important;
    top: -1050px !important;
    left: 350px !important;
}

Comment: This work only for this item. But if i add the tooltip to another item, then it remains at left 350px

Comment: Remove that code and replace it with

.ui-tooltip {
    position: absolute !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can check my simple solution for the same problem here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172398/2176096

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the presence of the jQuery UI libray, because it deals with classes of the same name, which end up messing with the bootstrap's tooltip styling and plecement. I just have to remove it to solve the issue.