# How to correctly remove bootstrap 4 tooltips when removing their DOM element with html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 project in which I have created a live search box. This box populates results that have tooltips that show a longer description than can fit in the search result space. I have made scripts in Jquery to hide the results and their parent div element when things happen such as the search box being emptied with html(''), or the user pressing a small X on the results to close it. When these events happen, if the cursor was over the result element, and therefore showing the tooltip, the tooltip is not removed when the elements are taken from the DOM.

Example:

```js
//script to hide the search when the text box is emptied of text.
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#liveSearch').on('keyup', function(){
        var searchstring = $(this).val();
        if (searchstring.length == 0 ){
            $('.quick-search-result').each(function() {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
                $(this).tooltip('dispose');
                $(this).remove();
              });
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
            $('.searchresults').hide();
            $('#searchresults').html('')
        }
    })
});
```

The tooltips are initialized with the following code elsewhere in the bottom of my index.php page.

```js
$(document).tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
```

As you can see in the code above, I've tried to use a few methods to remove the tooltips before the elements in question are removed from the DOM, but it does not seem to be working. (The same attempts exist in the other scripts that change the results with html(), which as the user typing more characters and getting new results. )

I found this similar question here:
[How to remove/hide bootstrap tooltip when element is removed from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421249/how-to-remove-hide-bootstrap-tooltip-when-element-is-removed-from-the-dom)

But I don't really understand some of the stuff mentioned, as I'm not using other frameworks mentioned there.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up finding the answer myself. I had not noticed that I had another instance of html('') used elsewhere in the code that was putting a search animation in the search results area before the results loaded, so I just needed to use the dispose method just before that too.